# How to add right click event handler for static text in mfc dialog?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog, static-text

Can anybody please let me know, how to add a right click event handler for a static text on a Dialog box.

So I have a modal dialog box, on which I have a static text control. When I am trying to add event handler for it,

I have only options:

```
STN_CLICKED
STN_DBCLK
STN_ENABLE
STN_DISABLE
NM_THEMECHANGED.
```

there is no message for right click. And I need to handle right click event. Can you please help me to know, is there any way to add right click event handler?

Comment: You can't. Better to subclass the static control and add your own right-button-down handler to that instead.

Comment: Can't you add a right-click to the dialog itself. Test the point for being on the Cstatic boundary? If so, show the menu?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is this ...

1. Make sure your static control has a unique ID, eg: `IDC_STATIC1`. It **can't** be IDC_STATIC.
2. Associate the control with a `CStatic` variable using the `ClassWizard`.
3. Override the `OnContextMenu` for your dialog using the editor.
4. Now you can do something like:

   ```
   void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point)
   {
       CRect rect;

       m_staticLabel.GetWindowRect(&rect);
       if (rect.PtInRect(point))
       {
           // Show context menu
       }
   }
   ```